# Not getting sessin value in vaadin framework

Tags: java, vaadin

Not getting sessin value in vaadin framework
Used below :

```
private void setCurrentUsername(String username){
    VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_IN_AS_USER",username);
    userSubMenu.setText(username);
}

public static String getCurrentUsername() {
    //log.info("User:::::::::::::::::" + (String) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().getAttribute("LOGGED_IN_AS_USER"));
    return (String) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().getAttribute("LOGGED_IN_AS_USER");
}
```

getting value as null when flow going to other class

Comment: Please edit your question with correct formatering

Comment: Why put this in a session at all? You can store it in the UI class itself

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

iIf you are using this for a user interface   i.e a user logging in. Don't forget that when your app first builds/ when the user first enters it they will of course have a null value(including any sub pages).

Try adding a ViewChangeListener to the page that the user now enters (apologies for any errors in coding i'm not currently able to gain access to my machine) into:

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
 this.username = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("LOGGED_IN_AS_USER");   
}
```